# Specify that lifetime of argument lasts for function call

Tags: rust, lifetime

I have a trait with a function that takes a reference to an iterator:

```
#[derive(Clone)]
struct Dog {
    name: &'static str,
}

trait DogListAction<'a, I>
where
    I: Iterator<Item = &'a Dog>,
{
    fn on_dog_list(&mut self, dog_list: I);
}

struct DogListActionExample {}

impl<'a, I> DogListAction<'a, I> for DogListActionExample
where
    I: Iterator<Item = &'a Dog>,
{
    fn on_dog_list(&mut self, dog_list: I) {
        for dog in dog_list {
            println!("{}", dog.name);
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let dogs = vec![Dog { name: "Pluto" }, Dog { name: "Lilly" }];
    let mut action_example = DogListActionExample {};
    let mut dog_list_actions: Vec<Box<DogListAction<_>>> = vec![Box::new(action_example)];
    loop {
        let dog_clone = dogs.clone();
        for dog_list_action in &mut dog_list_actions {
            dog_list_action.on_dog_list(dog_clone.iter());
        }
    }
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=e4fd032ea8affeb0df985811c5798f5d&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)

It does not take any reference to the elements, so there is no need for it to last for more time than the function call.

Due to my limited understanding of lifetimes, I do not know yet how to express this. Calling this function causes a compilation error:

```
error[E0597]: `dog_clone` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:33:41
   |
33 |             dog_list_action.on_dog_list(dog_clone.iter());
   |                                         ^^^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
34 |         }
35 |     }
   |     - `dog_clone` dropped here while still borrowed
36 | }
   | - borrowed value needs to live until here
```

I guess the borrow checker thinks that data in `dog_clone` may be referenced after the function ends, but this is not the case.

Comment: Could you please provide a [minimal example to reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), preferably with a playground link?  I can't see anything wrong with the code you showed.  (See also the [Rust tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) for more information.)

Comment: Here it is a link to a minimal example in the playground: 

https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=e4fd032ea8affeb0df985811c5798f5d&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015

Comment: I am still thinking that the problem is in the fact that the compiler thinks that DogListAction may reference data from the iterator even after the function is called. I am trying to add explicit lifetime specification but with no luck so far

Comment: @Clynamen, main problem here is that the code can potentially save short lived references to `dog_clone` elements in longer lived `dog_list_actions` elements.

Comment: If you replace `dog_clone.iter()` with `dogs.iter()`, the code will compile. You need to make signature of the function `on_dog_list()` express your intention to not save references the iterator produces.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking about that, but I don't know how to write that yet. What is the correct signature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that the code can potentially save short-lived references to `dog_clone` elements in the longer-lived `dog_list_actions`. We need to tell the compiler that we will not be saving references the iterator produces. It can be done like this:

```
trait DogListAction {
    fn on_dog_list<'a, I>(&'a mut self, dog_list: I)
    where
        I: Iterator<Item = &'a Dog>;
}
```

Now `Item`'s can live for the duration of `on_dog_list` call. In the original code they **must** live for longer duration.

But this code creates another problem: we can't box the trait `DogListAction` anymore as it includes generic function. The usual approach here is to use a trait object:

```
trait DogListAction {
    fn on_dog_list<'a>(&'a mut self, dog_list: Box<dyn Iterator<Item = &'a Dog> + 'a>);
}
```

Note the second `'a` in `Box<dyn Iterator<Item = &'a Dog> + 'a>`. Rust adds a `'static` trait bound to boxed trait objects by default and we don't want `'static` here.

```
#[derive(Clone)]
struct Dog {
    name: &'static str,
}

trait DogListAction {
    fn on_dog_list<'a>(&'a mut self, dog_list: Box<dyn Iterator<Item = &'a Dog> + 'a>);
}

struct DogListActionExample {}

impl DogListAction for DogListActionExample {
    fn on_dog_list<'a>(&'a mut self, dog_list: Box<dyn Iterator<Item = &'a Dog> + 'a>) {
        for dog in dog_list {
            println!("{}", dog.name);
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let dogs = vec![Dog { name: "Pluto" }, Dog { name: "Lilly" }];
    let action_example = DogListActionExample {};
    let mut dog_list_actions: Vec<Box<DogListAction>> = vec![Box::new(action_example)];
    {
        let dogs_clone = dogs.clone();
        for dog_list_action in &mut dog_list_actions {
            dog_list_action.on_dog_list(Box::new(dogs_clone.iter()));
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=c7b0ef2164407c5c3c84724658aca64e&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)